# Tricky Bevel - How to get better bevels?

Tags: bevel

The Security Access Tuner in Alien isolation caught my attention due to its tricky top left corner.

Any ideas how to replicate this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a try for this kind of topology, perhaps not a perfect topology but it works:

- The initial shape is rather easy to make from a plane, with some bevels and extrusions.
- But when you add and apply a Bevel modifier (Angle mode) it begins to mess up on some parts.
- You have to rework manually these parts with tris.
- Now it looks better, give it a Subsurf modifier and a Smooth Shading.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Bevels work best when there is a good amount of distance from one edge to another. The bevel tool (CTRL+B) can achieve this quite well. Alternatively, you can use a modifier, but it doesn't really make a whole lot of difference. It doesn't matter how fancy you get with it because it ultimately depends on one simple bevel of an edge of any type of shape.

Here's a demonstration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the already given solution you may want to use a modifier to apply some change to your mesh in a non-destructive way.

Here you can see some mesh I started with
[image: My base mesh]

I then applied a "Bevel" modifier with those parameters

[image: Modifier]

Here you can see the result
[image: End Result]

You can see in the modifier's image that you can even use a variety of methods to restrict the edges that are going to be beveled of even the method used.
This technique is very useful if you want to smooth your object and still be able to see the edges as you can see in the comparison below
[image: Smooth without bevel]

Here I clicked on smooth without the bevel modifier enabled

[image]

And here I enabled it

Keep in mind though that it can drastically increase the amount of polygons on your mesh so don't use your meshes as is in a video game. You can find plenty of tutorials out there on how to bake the details of a High poly mesh on a low poly mesh

Hope this helped

Comment: Also I'll probably use a gif next time if I can figure out how to make a video screen capture of my computer

Answer (score 0):

Its cool to see everybodys different interpretation of the shape in the screenshots

This is what I came up with that looks most like the image to me (there is still lots of room for improvement)

First I started off with a boolean modifier. A smaller cube with a bevelled corner was used
[image]
Next I found that adding an extra edge down the front (Knife Tool (K)) helped get an even bevel round the top edges. pressing C activates angle constraint to keep it straight.

[image]
Finally I applied the bevel through CTRL+B (I tried the bevel modifier with vertex groups and stuff but didn't really work) And that (to me) achieved the desired effect.

[image]

I feel there is more that could be done. I think the bevel I used is thicker than the one seen in the reference images and I'll definitely see about removing that triange (it is a flat surface so maybe it doesn't matter)

I feel like this may take awhile to get just right...

Thanks for the feedback!

[image]